# Export environment variables using script

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I need to set some environment variables in Ubuntu. I do the following and it works:

```
export PATH="/home/vagrant/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/vagrant/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/vagrant/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/vagrant/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:/home/vagrant/ns-allinone-2.35/lib"
export TCL_LIBRARY="/home/vagrant/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library"
```

But I move the same thing in a script `envexport.sh` and execute it, the environment variables are not getting set.

Where am I going wrong? How to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just run the script, the environment variables get destroyed when the script finishes.

Use `. envexport.sh`. That way the commands get executed in the current shell (environment).

Answer (score 2):

When you run a command in the shell, the shell creates a subprocess (child process). All the environment variables which were defined or changed down in the subprocess will be lost to the parent process.

However if you `source` a script, you force the script to run in the current process. That means environment variables in the script you ran will not be lost.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may help is if you will want those variables set for all of your sessions you can place the same commands in your .bashrc file by running the following command and pasting the lines in the file.

> vim ~/.bashrc

and the run

> source ~/.bashrc

in any terminals you currently are running.    If you start any new terminals they will automatically have your directories added to your path.